# ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function --> formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript

ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function in html code

```
   <form [formGroup]="editRoleForm" (ngSubmit)="onEditRole()" class="col s12" materialize>
      <div class="row">
         <select multiple formControlName="sp_id" id="permission_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="permissions"> // in this part ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Permissions</option>
          <option *ngFor="let permission of permissions" [value]="permission.permission_id">{{permission.permissin_desc}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

my ts code:

```
  'sp_id': this.fb.array([]),

  this.role.permissions.forEach(x => {
              (<FormArray>this.editRoleForm.get('sp_id')).push(new FormControl(x.permission_id)) 
             });
```

Can you suggest me what is the problem please?

I want to show like this example:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Seems you have already got the answer. Please don't duplicate questions

Comment: The problem here is that you're using FormArray control on select. But you can't

Comment: Can you suggest something ex?

Comment: Which data do you want to post to the server?

Comment: In this part I want to display in html array [{"permissions":[{"permsission_id":1,"permsission_desc":"show"},...{...}]

Comment: Because, when I want to edit this, in the first I want to look my value, on the second I want to delete or add some more permission. Look photo

Comment: Ok, thanks for the photo. I didn't notice multiple attribute and materialize

Comment: Are you using `angular2-materialize`?

Comment: Yes, When put 'sp_id': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), and this.role.permissions.forEach(x => { 
(this.editRoleForm.controls['sp_id']).patchValue([x.permission_id]) 
}); --> show only one value. 
not all value in array

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/8fBc6wVJxmpItap4Dxkm?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but that I want is to populate this form. My code   populateFormRole() {    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(     params => {        this.rs.getRoleById(params['id']).subscribe(          role => {
            this.role = role;
               this.editRoleForm.controls['name'].setValue(role.name);
               this.editRoleForm.controls['active'].setValue(role.active);
               this.role.permissions.forEach(x => {
              (this.editRoleForm.controls['sp_id']).setValue([x.permission_id]) 
            });   }    )  }   ); }

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FpiBmGHixTBFPURnu3Ek?p=preview

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. :)